# How should i map my request body to another object while maintaining the same children relationship?

Tags: java, json, arraylist, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I have a request body with this model class:

```
public class IvrRequest {
    int age;
    String name;
    String address;
    List<IvrRequest> children;
}
```

I want to map this to another model of class like:

```
public class IvrMapper {
    int id;
    String name;
    List<IvrMapper> resourceElements;
}
```

What approach should i use for this?

Example:-

```
{
    "age":16,
    "name":"Rohit",
    "address":"adgsgdsdfgsdfgsf",
    "children":[
    {
        "age":16,
        "name":"Rohit",
        "address":"adgsgdsdfgsdfgsf",
        "children":[{
            "age":16,
            "name":"Rohit",
            "address":"adgsgdsdfgsdfgsf"                
        }]
    },
    {
        "age":45,
        "name":"Singh",
        "address":"45afasdfas54df6asdf",
        "children":[{
            "age":55,
            "name":"nitin",
            "address":"@%^%@#^Ghagdhasdhg"              
        }]
    }]
}
```

This is an example for the request body.

Comment: What's the problem with iterating the `List<IvrRequest>` and for each element create the other entity?

Comment: I cant change the definition of classes

Comment: Is there a way this can be done with DFS?

Comment: You have two `POJO` classes which you can not change and you want to map the same `JSON` payload to two of them, am I right?

Comment: Yes ...but fields are different in both POJO class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not specify which library do you use so I propose to use [`Jackson`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind) which allows fast and easy deserialising from `JSON` to `Java` model and from one `POJO` to other. If you can not change class or class belongs to `3-rd party` library you can always use [`MixIn` feature](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations). Below example show how to:

- Deserialise `JSON` to `IvrRequest`
- Deserialise `JSON` to `IvrMapper`
- Convert `IvrRequest` to `IvrMapper`

Simple app:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.addMixIn(IvrMapper.class, IvrMapperMixIn.class);

        System.out.println("Parse IvrRequest model: ");
        IvrRequest ivrRequest = mapper.readValue(jsonFile, IvrRequest.class);
        System.out.println(ivrRequest);

        System.out.println("Parse IvrMapper model: ");
        System.out.println(mapper.readValue(jsonFile, IvrMapper.class));

        System.out.println("Convert IvrRequest to IvrMapper");
        System.out.println(mapper.convertValue(ivrRequest, IvrMapper.class));
    }
}

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
interface IvrMapperMixIn {

    @JsonProperty("age")
    int getId();

    @JsonProperty("children")
    List<IvrMapper> getResourceElements();
}

class IvrRequest {

    private int age;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private List<IvrRequest> children;

    // getters, setters, toString
}

class IvrMapper {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private List<IvrMapper> resourceElements;

    // getters, setters, toString
}
```

Above app prints:

```
Parse IvrRequest model: 
age=16, name='Rohit', address='adgsgdsdfgsdfgsf'
 children=
    age=16, name='Rohit', address='adgsgdsdfgsdfgsf'
 children=
    age=16, name='Rohit', address='adgsgdsdfgsdfgsf'

    age=45, name='Singh', address='45afasdfas54df6asdf'
 children=
    age=55, name='nitin', address='@%^%@#^Ghagdhasdhg'


Parse IvrMapper model: 
id=16, name='Rohit'
 resourceElements=
    id=16, name='Rohit'
 resourceElements=
    id=16, name='Rohit'

    id=45, name='Singh'
 resourceElements=
    id=55, name='nitin'


Convert IvrRequest to IvrMapper
id=16, name='Rohit'
 resourceElements=
    id=16, name='Rohit'
 resourceElements=
    id=16, name='Rohit'

    id=45, name='Singh'
 resourceElements=
    id=55, name='nitin'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man.....This was great way to do it
But can i do it without using any library and manually parsing using DFS or recursion?

Comment: @rohitsingh, of course you can do that manually using recursion but I do not see any reason to do it this way. Could you explain why do you want to do that manually?

Comment: Actually i am not allowed to use any external library or method ....just want to use some algorithm

Comment: This is just a reference actual problem is much complex and this feature won't work on that one....so need to use some algorithm

Comment: @rohitsingh, so what is your input - `JSON` file? Or `IvrRequest` object? What do you mean by "i am not allowed to use any external library" - can you use only internal `JDK` classes? Do you have a list of allowed libraries? I think you should create new question with link to this one and explicitly tell what is an input and and output and which classes can you use.

Comment: There is an api which is taking IvrRequest as request body . So i need to map this request to IvrMapper class using some algorithm and without using any external libraries.
I just want to know can this done by manually parsing the elements and setting it in the same hierarchy in IvrMapper class using recursion or DFS.